# xml2struct with missing/optional values

Tags: matlab

I am using xml2struct to transform a xml file to a struct. It can be the case that certain optional nodes do not exist in the xml file. I would like to detect this and insert 'NULL' fields into the struct. I understand that there is no NULL in MATLAB. So I wonder what experienced users tend to use to represent missing/optional values.

I am using these data types:

```
char
logical
double
```

Comment: I tend to have a preference for `NaN` or blank space `''`

Comment: problem with NaN is that if I assign it to a boolean the data type changes to double.

Comment: That's a good point there, didn't think of that.  Would it be worth it to you to test the boolean later for a value of 1 or 0 or NaN (for empty?)  Not sure what you plan on using the struct for once you pull the data in.

Comment: Are you saying that I should set a logical to double by assigning NaN and then check for NaN to check whether it is missing (NULL)?

Comment: I tend to use the empty matrix [], it will return 1 for an isfloat() on a struct item, but it will also return isempty() which should allow you to screen for it.

Comment: I have decided to use NaN to indicate NULL. Please create an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to have a preference for `NaN` or blank space `''`.  Now granted that using `NaN` for a logical you will change the datatype to double and create a scenario in which you need to test for `1` or `0` instead of `True` or `False`.